# how to run flask app in localhost with SSL

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, openssl, ssl-certificate

I tried to run my Flask Application on localhost and as well as on my local network's IP address and it ran very well (without SSL).

However, when I tried to run the application with SSL then the web browsers didn't load the page and gives the error:

> Your connection is not private : NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

Methods I have tried but failed:

**1. Using Self-signed `.pem` certificate (Subject Type=CA)**

With generated certificate `.pem`, cert key, and configuring my flask app use it.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365


app.run(
    host='192.168.1.127', port="8282", debug=True,
    ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'),
)
```

**2. Using Self-signed `.crt` certificate**

With generated certificate `.crt`, cert key, and configuring my flask app use it.

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
$ cp server.key server.key.org
$ openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

app.run(
    host='192.168.1.127', port="8282", debug=True,
    ssl_context=('server.crt', 'server.key')
)
```

**3. Run Flask with `ssl_context='adhoc'`**

````
```
app.run(
    host='192.168.1.127', port="8282", debug=True,
    ssl_context='adhoc'
)
```
````

I am trying to build a system where multiple raspberry pi are located at different rooms of the house but they are connected to the same home network.

There is the main computer on the same network which acts as a Controller and to implement the system successfully I need to make requests from the controller system to all the Raspberry PI over HTTPS.

[image: Screenshot of browser with "your connection is not private" error message]

Comment: I doubt this is Flask-specific; have you looked over posts like [How do I run proper HTTPS on an Internal Network?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/121163) and [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2043617) to see what options you have?

Comment: You really want to set up an internal DNS server or sync your /etc/hosts files across your raspberries, so you can use a host name instead of an IP address. Browsers rightly refuse to accept SSL certificates for private network IP addresses such as 192.168.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

Its working.

The message *connection not private* is misleading. What is actually happening is the connection is encrypted with a certificate that is not in your chain of trust. Even if it was, I doubt the browser would accept a certificate for an IP address.

In any case, your connection is indeed encrypted.

You don't show the additional details. But you can try to add the generated certificate to your system's chain of trust.